# Nested loop on list string python ,

Tags: python, string

I want to iterate the second loop through the second position

My error is

> Exception has occurred: TypeError       (note: full exception trace is shown but execution is paused at: )
> can only concatenate list (not "int") to list

```
s = "dog cat cat dog"

b = list(s.split(" "))

for x in b:

    for y in str(b+1):

        print(x,'/', y)
```

Comment: what  b +1 meant to do?, you can't add 1 to a list!

Comment: What is the expected output / What do you try to achieve? Please provide some more details. thank

Comment: I want to start the second loop which would be second to x index

[dog, cat , cat , dog]
x  = dog
y = cat

Comment: How to make a loop on Which if it finds same word it should replace it with 1 and move in the same way

like [dog,cat,cat,dog]
output should be [1,2,2,1]

Answer (score 0):

A way to fix your code is:

```
s = "dog cat cat dog"

b = list(s.split(" "))

for x in b:

    for y in b[1:]:

        print(x,'/', y)
```

Even though I don't think it does what it is supposed to do, because the output is:

```
dog / cat
dog / cat
dog / dog
cat / cat
cat / cat
cat / dog
cat / cat
cat / cat
cat / dog
dog / cat
dog / cat
dog / dog
```

Maybe you wanted something like

```
s = "dog cat cat dog"
b = list(s.split(" "))
for x,y in zip(b,b[1:]):
    print(x,'/', y)
```

Output:

```
dog / cat
cat / cat
cat / dog
```

Comment: How to make a loop on Which if it finds same word it should replace it with 1 and move in the same way

like [dog,cat,cat,dog]
output should be [1,2,2,1]

Answer (score 0):

As you specified in your comments, "dog cat cat dog" should return [1, 2, 2, 1]. I am not sure why you want this, but perhaps this code solves your problem?

```
s = "dog cat cat dog"
b = s.split(" ")

score = [0] * len(b)
for i in range(len(b)):
    for j in range(1, len(b)):
        if b[i] == b[j]:
            score[i] += 1
```

Running the code gives `score=[1, 2, 2, 1]`.

Comment: How to make a loop on Which if it finds same word it should replace it with 1 and move in the same way

like [dog,cat,cat,dog]
output should be [1,2,2,1]